# Alexa api site info xml format to php values

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, alexa-internet

I try to make use of the alexa api by amazon. I want to receive website data.

I create a url to receive the data, I get this in a xml format.

When I try to read this file by

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

I get just the code 'SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) '.

How can I get the data to php from this xml?

A Part of the xml file I get ;

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/"><aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11"><aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>removed</aws:RequestId></aws:OperationRequest><aws:UrlInfoResult><aws:Alexa>

  <aws:TrafficData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">yahoo.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:Rank>4</aws:Rank>
    <aws:UsageStatistics>
      <aws:UsageStatistic>
        <aws:TimeRange>

      <aws:Months>3</aws:Months>
    </aws:TimeRange>
    <aws:Rank>
      <aws:Value>4</aws:Value>
      <aws:Delta>0</aws:Delta>
    </aws:Rank>
    <aws:Reach>

      <aws:Rank>
        <aws:Value>4</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>0</aws:Delta>
      </aws:Rank>
      <aws:PerMillion>
        <aws:Value>228,260</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>-2.83%</aws:Delta>

      </aws:PerMillion>
    </aws:Reach>
    <aws:PageViews>
      <aws:PerMillion>
        <aws:Value>14,390</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>-10.59%</aws:Delta>
      </aws:PerMillion>
      <aws:Rank>
```

Comment: You should check the [SimpleXMLElement dokumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to get an overview of the data access options of that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is more or less what you need:

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response, null, false, 'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05');
    if(count($xml)) 
    {
        $info = (string)$xml->TrafficData->DataUrl->Alexa;
    }
```

notes:

- i'm feeding in the namespace: 'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05'
- chain a path to the element that you want, where $xml is the root element.
- cast an element to string to get its text node